# "end meets the means" or similar phrase meaning (confused)

Tags: meaning, phrases

Was wondering what this phrase is meant to be..(means fit the end / end meets the means) - or something like that.. when saying the action your doing although perceived as excessive..is worth it for the result u require..

i have tried google and other websites including this one..and just cannot find the phrase anywhere yet cant remember it exactly myself lol...was wondering if anyone knew the phrase and its origin and meaning of it..

Comment: I think you meant "the end justifies the means"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are proably looking for "the end justifies the means". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_end_justifies_the_means) defines it as:

> Morally wrong actions are sometimes necessary to achieve morally right outcomes; actions can only be considered morally right or wrong by virtue of the morality of the outcome.